# Transforming a path in svg-editor, method draw using user-input values

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-edit

I am wondering if it would be possible to resize a path using values inputted by the user after he draws the path. Setting the width and height for example.

I am currently using the transform attribute within a JS function to do that but while the path gets resized, the handles of the path stay in the original position which makes the thing a total mess.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code you've written so far so we can comment on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the path is is selected:

`svgCanvas.changeSelectedAttribute("transform", "scale(0.5, 1)");`

Comment: yes the handles of the path however are  not refreshed. they stay at the original position. Any ideas?

Comment: Draw the path with the pencil tool, then open the console and paste the code snippet, do the handles resize?